# Too Many Arguments to 'Public sub New()' error for checkbox location (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I am getting this error for following line. (Blue wiggly line Under (35, 31))

```
Dim chkbx1 as New Checkbox    
chkbx1.Location = New Point(35, 31)
```

what are the causes of this error? is there any other way to give location of checkbox?

Comment: Your statements are correct so the problem must exist somewhere else. Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have another `Point` class defined somewhere.

Try the following:

```
Dim chkbx1 As New CheckBox
chkbx1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35, 31)
```